# how do I write this php code

Tags: php, apache

could you please advise how do i write this php code correctly:

```
if (function_exists('apache_get_modules')) {
apache_get_modules()
and other related code
}
else {
no support for apache modules, maybe phpinfo show some related info
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the code meant to do?

Comment: to see if the apache_get_modules() functions exists, if not than write "no support for apache modules"

Comment: `function_exists('apache_get_modules') ? apache_get_modules() : print('no support for apache modules');` :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<?php
if (function_exists('apache_get_modules')) {
    // call the function
    apache_get_modules();
    // write your other related code
}
else{
    // show message 
    echo "no support for apache modules";
    // get php info
    phpinfo();
}
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/u170201516/public_html/test.php on line 2

Comment: So... what's on line one? If it's not `<?php` then that's your problem.